# Sending serial data to A855

Tags: bluetooth, usb

All,
I have researched and found some say it is possible to send serial data to the A855 either through the usb port or through bluetooth. I am in need of sending data to the phone from a pic in a project I am working on for school. Which is the best path to use, and does anyone have any source code or references I can look at to get a better idea? Any help would be appreciated. Also, I want to have the phone run a program with the data and possibly use data from the accelerometer in the phone. Is this difficult to do if I want to send the phone serial data as well? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Trevor

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at the android bluetooth based chat example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)

It uses the Bluetooth Serial Port Profile